# WebServiceexception “No Content-type in the header” when trying to consume Apache Tomcat hosted webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, cxf

I am getting wsdl url of remote webservice which is deployed on apache tomcat. I am converting into java client using CXF, when calling method of web services getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: No Content-type in the header!
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy30.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.exp.webservice.IWebService_WebServiceImplPort_Client.main(IWebService_WebServiceImplPort_Client.java:59)
```

Comment: Someone here has same problem and the reason for it was the trailing slash in the webservice-URL: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1102258

Answer (score 0):

That's not a CXF client.   That's using the in-JDK JAX-WS implementation.

In either case, use something like Wireshark to trace what is on the wire.  It looks like the server is responding with some sort of invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but when properly checked whether the WSDL url was working or not, the issue got fixed.